# Run-time error ‘1004’: Method ‘Name’ of object ‘_Worksheet’ failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have inherited a file to perform a task. Whenever I run the "**Process**" button I get this error:
**Run-time error ‘1004’: Method ‘Name’ of object ‘_Worksheet’ failed**

Pressing the `Process` button should do the following:

1. Create new workbooks with a set filename
2. Filter data from the `Data` sheet
3. Copy filtered data in the created workbooks, separate sheets (renamed according to filters)

I have marked the code accordingly with: 'THIS IS THE LINE THE DEBUG POINTS OUT

**Additional information, this code runs perfectly in a windows machine. I encounter this issue when using Mac.**

I am very, very new to VBA, any help and guidance are appreciated.

```
Sub Process()

Run "Openfiles"

   Dim x As Long, y As Long, teamtrgt As String, filetrgt As String, Celltrgt As String
   Dim cellrange As Long, OMtrgt As String, ws As Worksheet
      
    Windows("Macro file - extract and harvest v2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Macro Sheet").Select
x = 1
y = 0
cellrange = Range("a16").Value


Do Until x = Range("c1").Value

    Range("D" & (x + 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
teamtrgt = Range("G2").Value
OMtrgt = Range("h2").Value
filetrgt = Range("i2").Value


On Error GoTo Sheetadd
    Windows(filetrgt & ".xlsx").Activate
    Sheets(teamtrgt).Select
    GoTo SheetExisting
    
Sheetadd:
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = teamtrgt 'THIS IS THE LINE THE DEBUG POINTS OUT
    End With

    
    Windows("Macro file - extract and harvest v2.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(filetrgt & ".xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Resume Next

    
SheetExisting:

    Windows("Macro file - extract and harvest v2.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Macro Sheet").Select
 Celltrgt = Range("j2").Value
    
    
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("D1").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$" & cellrange).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=teamtrgt

    Range("A2:P" & cellrange).Select
   ' Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlVisible)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(filetrgt & ".xlsx").Activate
        Sheets(teamtrgt).Select
    Range("A" & Celltrgt).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
    Windows("Macro file - extract and harvest v2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Select
       ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Macro Sheet").Select

x = x + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `teamtrgt` when the error occurs?

Comment: @BigBen , I just checked and saw that it was blank (seems it was deleted).  Also, G2:V743 in the Macro Sheet was highlighted and some other row range in columns A:P is cut (you know that broken line when you cut [command + x]).

Comment: You can't name a sheet an empty string, put a value into i2 on the macro sheet and the error will go away (don't name it an existing sheet name though).

Comment: I understand that I can't use a blank cell to set a name for the sheet, the thing is the code should not be deleting information in that cell in the first place. The code I posted works in a Windows machine (no errors whatsoever), the error only happens in my Mac.

Comment: Is it a copy of the workbook or the exact same one that works on windows and not on mac? I'm skeptical we can answer this more concretely because the flow of this code leaves something to be desired. Step through and see if it is deleting that cell at some point.

Comment: The code's error handlers don't differentiate between errors so it will hit that line no matter what the error is, and since the code relies entirely on select and activate, based on where the code fails it could be using the wrong sheet or workbook, but we can't know that without actually watching the code do its thing.

Comment: It's the exact same one that works on windows, but I had to modify the file creation path to have "/"  instead of "\". Is there a way to share files here?

Comment: I mean you can post a link to a file share but its not very likely, for very good reasons, that anyone here is going to download a random .xlsm file.